# Output only subdocument in MongoDB find

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that looks like the JSON below (collection consist of output from a MapReduce query, so I don't have much flexibility to redesign the document schema)

```
{ _id: '1234', value: { empId: '1234', naSales: '101000', euSales: '102000' } }
{ _id: '9820', value: { empId: '9820', naSales: '302000', euSales: '200000', asiaSales: '230000' } }
```

How to write query such way to output only sub-document saved in the 'value' field?

```
{ empId: '9820', naSales: '302000', euSales: '200000', asiaSales: '230000' }
```

I know I could do `collection.find({_id: 0})` to avoid returning _id field, but result will still be nested.

```
{ value: { empId: '9820', naSales: '302000', euSales: '200000', asiaSales: '230000' } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use aggregation pipeline with `$replaceRoot` stage to populate value as a root level document from mongo 3.4+

```
db.col.aggregate(
    [
        //$match or other agg stages here
        {$replaceRoot : {newRoot : "$value"}}
    ]
)
```

result

```
> db.col.aggregate(
... [
... {$replaceRoot : {newRoot : "$value"}}
... ]
... )
{ "empId" : "1234", "naSales" : "101000", "euSales" : "102000" }
{ "empId" : "9820", "naSales" : "302000", "euSales" : "200000", "asiaSales" : "230000" }
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of projection and JavaScript map function to transform the output into the shape you want:

`db.mycollection.find({}, {value: 1, _id: 0}).map(e => e.value)`

That query returns

```
[
    {
        "empId" : "1234",
        "naSales" : "101000",
        "euSales" : "102000"
    },
    {
        "empId" : "9820",
        "naSales" : "302000",
        "euSales" : "200000",
        "asiaSales" : "230000"
    }
]
```

This is the environment I ran that command on:

```
~ $which mongo
/usr/local/bin/mongo
~ $mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.4.3
git version: f07437fb5a6cca07c10bafa78365456eb1d6d5e1
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
allocator: system
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

Before doing so, I populated `mycollection` with the two documents you provided:

```
db.mycollection.insert({ _id: '1234', value: { empId: '1234', naSales: '101000', euSales: '102000' } })
db.mycollection.insert({ _id: '9820', value: { empId: '9820', naSales: '302000', euSales: '200000', asiaSales: '230000' } })
```